# Grouping a Rails collection_select by a field's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, grouped-collection-select

I would like to have the following `collection_select` be grouped by `State`, which is a field on `Tuning` that is either `Public` or `Private`. Is this possible?

In the view:

```
<%= collection_select :tunings, :tuning, @fretboard_tuning_options, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "", id: "tuning", style: 'width: 100%;' } %>
```

In the controller:

```
@fretboard_tuning_options = Tuning.where('state=? OR user_id=?', 'Public', current_user.id)
```

Any tuning with a State of Public will not overlap with those that have user_id = current_user.id. The goal is to have a dropdown box (I am using Select2 to format the dropdown) that shows two groups of options: Public and Private, and under each group are the relevant Tunings. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want `grouped_collection_select`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: From that link, it looks like `grouped_collection_select` is for use with a `has_many` relationship, not when grouping by the value of a field on a single model. Is this usable in my case? Thanks